# TeX-evince-sync-view locking up with this file

Tags: auctex, pdf, tex

This file when I compile it with AUCTeX, and then try to view it, using TeX-evince-sync-view, shows that one page has been compiled, but then shows a blank view. After I kill it, `TeX-evince-sync-view` stops responding properly, and gives me a `D-Bus error: "call timed out" message.`I suppose this is because the file is generated in a subdirectory, but AUCTeX really should cope better. Can anyone reproduce this?

Suggestions on what to do, and also how to unstop D-Bus in this sort of situation (just for my reference) would be helpful. Should I report this, and if so, where? AUCTeX version is 12.1.2 (elpa). I see that there is a reporting bugs to AUCTeX inside Emacs. Should I use that?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{bar.tex}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}  % This will be output to bar
\node [font=\bfseries\Large, align=center] at (7, 4.1){TEST};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\ShellEscape{pdflatex -shell-escape bar.tex}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I could be wrong but that does seem to be a recipe for disaster in ANY editor rather than a simple call from a command line. the editor is potentially holding locks on any files in progress then you tell pdfLaTeX to mess about with the currently open files, hence its like sitting on a branch with a saw in the wrong hand. you might get away with a copy of ./foo/bar.tex to ./foo/car.tex then pdfLaTeX car.tex

Comment: Hi KJO. Not sure what you mean by "the editor is potentially holding locks on any files in progress". What files are those? Can you elaborate?

Comment: The editing system has opened a fresh file \begin{filecontents*}{foo/bar.tex}
and will have the rights to  to exclusively add each line \end file may not be closing the file (just in case you might add to it) then with a shell-escape you are commanding pdfLaTeX to process that exact same file

Comment: Oh, I see. Sounds like I need to tell whoever/whatever to close the file, then. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: NO (apart from close editor thus ending the editors grip) hence the suggestion to try a copy and run the command on a copy then do whats required next using the processed copy, certainly its an issue for the editor developer to advise if the system is holding files open in such cases, although one could argue it is the way that TeX is providing the \end{filecontents} command

Comment: OK it does work oddly If Hello is in main and world is in bar then I need to run 2 or three times to get page1 with hello and page 2 showing world as a simple include the noticeable warning was that bar.tex had a problem with the \usepackage{annot} (not finding the annot.sty) which also happens for me in main since I don't have that package in miktex

Comment: Yes If I comment out annot It runs as you might expect (nicely on windows texworks) It would take me a while to switch to auctex/evince and it would not be full proof since I would not be using the d-bus communication so the question is will it work for you without annot ?

Comment: Actually I cant find such a package and that may be the issue that the secondary run is sticking in an error so you would need to have the nonstop option active pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode  bar.tex

Comment: Hi. The `annot` package call was commented out, so I am not sure why you were mentioning it. Maybe you accidentally uncommented it? I've now removed it completely. It's just a local package that adds a grid to a PGF picture environment - I got it from a TeX SE answer. And the file was originally `foo/bar.pdf`, but I realised that it made no difference, so I changed it to just `bar.pdf`.

Comment: I suggest add the nonstopmode command to a fresh main file with a new subfile name (change all 3 or 4 places) this is to ensure there is no "history" for a previous run then try again

Comment: I think AUCTeX runs in nonstop mode anyway. And how is that relevant?

Comment: In case you're wondering, the annot "package" corresponds to this answer - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39698/3406. Probably not the best name.

Comment: In hindsight the now remove error condition during the call to compile bar.tex would culminate in a  D-Bus error: "call timed out" message since IF THERE WERE an error condition in a shell command then the spawned pdfLaTeX process will stall without a directive to deliberately continue (it is blindly waiting in the dark for a never to be gotten reply) this is the reason there is a pdfLaTeX -interaction= parameter which in this case needs to be set to nonstopmode Thus its good that there previously was one to trigger this revelation thus you should now be able to use that in your own answer ?

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me. "the now remove error condition"? If you mean the annot package line, that has no relevance. Everything compiled fine. But when the viewer came up, it was empty, and after that `TeX-evince-sync-view` would no longer respond properly.

Comment: It was the call to a not available annot in your sample that highlighted the need for nonstop running of pdfLaTeX, so that it can hand back to auctex. The dbus message indicates the call probably stalled and it waits until time out. Then auctex has nothing to show

Comment: No, it wasn't. As I already mentioned, the annot line was commented out, and has nothing to do with the issue described. Try the current MWE. You'll see it has the same problem.

Comment: As I mentioned your current mwe has no content nor anything to include you need  anything after begin document for a first page and you need an \includegraphics or similar to import bar.pdf for second page

Comment: That's true. The main page has no content. But that's still no reason for the T`eX-evince-sync-view` process (or whatever it is), to lock up.

Comment: I guess if there is nothing to sync it just borks so that puts it into the handling between emacs and evince possibly how they use synctex

Comment: I've compiled blank pages before. Emacs/AUCTeX wasn't bothered by it.

Comment: Its NOT a blank page with mwe there is NO page LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file ./bar.tex'. \openout15 = bar.tex'. runsystem(pdflatex -shell-escape bar.tex)...executed. Here is how much of TeX's memory you used: 12320 strings out of 494590 No pages of output It builds a main.pdf filename but it has zero bytes the bar.pdf is of course OK

Comment: Well, ok. Empty page. Maybe that's a pathological condition, but AUCTeX should be able to handle it without freaking out.

Comment: I just threw the empty pdf at evince for windows and it shows NO ENTRY sign "unable to open" so the background handover of auctex to evince with an empty file might be the issue, see if just adding Hello before \begin{filecontents*}{bar.tex} at least confirms that supposition